# React Native. Modification in third party package

Tags: react-native

I am using giftedChat for my project but I modified the module itself (I changed Message.js)
My question is : how can I make this modification persistant after runnning npm install again etc...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make use of patch-package. This is the npm link: https://www.npmjs.com/package/patch-package

The command for creating a patch is:

```
yarn patch-package package-name
```

This will create a patches folder which will contain the patch. Then every time you install node-modules, the patch will get applied and your changes will remain.